# Angular: Save Google Login information in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created google login in angular but now want to use localStorage to save the information but after trying a lot, I am unable to do this.

```
providers: [
{
  provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
  useValue: {
    autoLogin: false,
    providers: [
      {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
          '.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        )
      }
    ]
  } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
}
```

],

```
ngOnInit(): void {
// var navbarNav = document.getElementsByClassName("");
this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
  this.user = user;
  localStorage.setItem('googleUserName', this.user.name);
  localStorage.getItem('googleUserName');
  console.log(this.user.name)
  console.log(localStorage)
})
```

}

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCZYU.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GocT.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First screenshot is for connect my application with google service.
  signInWithGoogle() {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }
This code applied when the method signInWithGoogle() triggered once and then I want to save the login information in localStorage.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea at all.   https://snyk.io/blog/is-localstorage-safe-to-use/

Comment: @Lynx242
signInWithGoogle() {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    console.log(this.user.name);
  }

When I use this user in my html by adding {{user.name}}, it's working nicely. But while trying to console, it's showing an error that "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: Please add the relevant code as code blocks in your question. See why: [Why should I not post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6294072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so if you want to safe if it in the local storage it goes this way.

**store the information**. `googleUserName` is just an identifier, it could also be a string like `XRZ3334BRET` or `Frank`.

```
 localStorage.setItem('googleUserName', this.user.name);
```

**load the information**

```
 localStorage.getItem('googleUserName');
```

**remove the information** from local storage use

```
 localStorage.removeItem('googleUserName');
```

Comment: Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It's showing this following error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at NavbarComponent.signInWithGoogle (navbar.component.ts:66)
    at NavbarComponent_button_45_Template_button_click_0_listener (navbar.component.html:49)
...

Comment: I thought you already have the `user` object? Please, don't get me wrong, but at which point in your train of thought are you referring to the code? Do you already know how to get the response of Google?

Comment: Right now the name is showing in the console.log after writing the code in nginit.
ngOnInit(): void {
    // var navbarNav = document.getElementsByClassName("");
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      localStorage.setItem('googleUserName', this.user.name);
      localStorage.getItem('googleUserName');
      console.log(this.user.name)
      console.log(localStorage)
    })
  }

But now I need to keep the information of goole username in localstorage that will be remain stable after closing the browser and starting the browser again.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem by following your solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) Please, be so kind and mark my answer as solution. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer. You can retrieve the users name from the authentication response.
`const userName = user.name;`
Then store it in the browser storage.
`localStorage.setItem('userName ', JSON.stringify(userName ));`